# Get header and footer with FileHelpers

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I`m using filehelpers to open a fixed file but the file has header and footer, I got all records in the file except for them by using IgnoreFirst and IgnoreLast but I wish to get them somehow, how can I do that?

```
    FileHelperEngine<InputRecord> engine_I = new FileHelperEngine<InputRecord>();
    List<InputRecord> input                = null;

    try
    {
        input              = engine_I.ReadFile(path).ToList();
        HeaderClass head   = //getheader
        FooterClass footer = //getfooter
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Erro treatments
    }
```

MY CLASS:

```
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
[IgnoreLast(1)]
[FixedLengthRecord()]
public class InputRecord
{
        [FieldFixedLength(1)]
        public string something1;


        [FieldFixedLength(20)]
        public string something2;


        [FieldFixedLength(8)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
        public DateTime date1;


        [FieldFixedLength(8)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
        public DateTime date2;

        [FieldFixedLength(24)]
        public string something3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the `FileEngine.BeforeReadRecord` and `FileEngine.AfterReadRecord` events could be used, as demonstated at https://www.filehelpers.net/example/EventsAndNotification/ReadEvents/